# SWT TableItem getText doesn't return what I expect

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I want to swap two texts in `TableItem`s. Firstly, I set the text, then I check which `TableItem`s are selected, save them in 2 variables and overwrite them. But I get these strings instead of the message I wanted:

`[Lorg.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;@6fadae5d`

The part after the `@` is always different, I guess it's an ID or something but I can't find a solution. Here's the code snippets. `groupsList` is a `String` array.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= logic.amountOfGroups; i++) {

        Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER);
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
        for (int j = 0; j < logic.personsInGroup; j++) {
            TableItem tableItem_1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            tableItem_1.setText(logic.groupsList.get(i - 1)[j]);
        }
        tableList.add(table);
    }
```

So I wrote the content into the TableItems, then I want to swap them:

```
swapButton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    swapButton.setText("Swap");
    swapButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            int[] playerIndices = new int[2];
            int[] groupIndices = new int[2];
            int i = 0;
            String toBeSwappedZero = "";
            String toBeSwappedOne = "";
            for (Table table : tableList) {
                if (table.getSelectionCount() == 1) {
                    if (toBeSwappedZero == "") {
                        groupIndices[0] = i;
                        playerIndices[0] = table.getSelectionIndex();
                        toBeSwappedZero = table.getSelection().toString();
                    } else {
                        groupIndices[1] = i;
                        playerIndices[1] = table.getSelectionIndex();
                        toBeSwappedOne = table.getSelection().toString();
                    }
                }
                if (table.getSelectionCount() == 2) {
                    playerIndices = table.getSelectionIndices();
                    groupIndices[0] = i;
                    groupIndices[1] = i;
                    toBeSwappedZero = table.getItem(playerIndices[0]).getText();
                    toBeSwappedOne = table.getItem(playerIndices[1]).getText();
                }
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(toBeSwappedOne);
            tableList.get(groupIndices[0]).getItem(playerIndices[0]).setText(toBeSwappedOne);
            tableList.get(groupIndices[1]).getItem(playerIndices[1]).setText(toBeSwappedZero);
        }
    });
```

Here's the GUI[image]

Comment: What part of all that code is giving this result? `[Lorg.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;@6fadae5d` is what you would get by calling `toString` on an array of table items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look these lines in your `MouseAdapter`:

```
if (table.getSelectionCount() == 1) {
    if (toBeSwappedZero == "") {
        // ...
        toBeSwappedZero = table.getSelection().toString();
    } else {
        // ...
        toBeSwappedOne = table.getSelection().toString();
    }
}
```

Notice that [`Table.getSelection()`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.html#getSelection--) returns an array of `TableItem` objects. As @greg-449 pointed out, you'll get `[Lorg.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;@XXXXXXXX` if you call `toString()` on that array.

In each of those two cases you've already checked that there is only one `TableItem` selected, so you can safely do `table.getSelection()[0]` to access that `TableItem` *(Alternatively, you could do `table.getItem(table.getSelectionIndex())` after verifying that there is at least one and only one item selected)*.

In an unrelated `if`-statement later on, you're correctly getting the `TableItem` text:

```
table.getItem(playerIndices[0]).getText();
```

So instead of using the `toString()` method on those two lines at the start, you'll want to use `getText()` as you've done here.

Comment: Thanks, can't test right now but this is probably it.

Comment: No problem - let me know if it doesn't work for some reason and I'd be happy to take another look.